# how to ask web scraper to wait till javascript functions are not executed?

Tags: python

I have to scrape a web page that has a bunch of dates. The problem is that when the page loads, it shows "Wait for a moment" and then after a second or two, it shows dates. The Python requests library reads the html from the webpage and when I search for the class using BeautifulSoup that contains date, it returns 'Wait for a moment' instead of dates.
`

```
html= requests.get(url).text
date_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tag = date_soup.find_all(class_='Subhead-heading js-date-range')
print(tag[0])
```

`

Comment: I don't think BeautifulSoup executes any Javascript. Consider [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html).

Comment: `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't execute `JavaScript`. You need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which runs `JavaScript`